# How to approach $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{a}\frac{\sin^{-1}e^x+\sec^{-1}e^{-x}}{(\tan^{-1}e^a+ \tan^{-1}e^x)(e^x+e^{-x})}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

How to approach this integral?

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{a}\frac{\sin^{-1}e^x+\sec^{-1}e^{-x}}{(\tan^{-1}e^a+ \tan^{-1}e^x)(e^x+e^{-x})}\mathrm{d}x$$

[image: question]

Comment: There are countably many random integrals, most of them not solvable in elementary functions. Why this one?

Comment: @NoNames this ones from a test paper and they would definitely give a solvable one

Comment: Then, I'd advise to include such information in your question. It might increase your chance to get an answer.

Comment: @Anusha Not that it may help much, but were any bounds given for a?

Comment: @IshraaqParvez nope

Comment: Except for it being real

Comment: If $\sin^{-1} e^x$ is meant to be $\arcsin e^x$, that isn't even defined for $x>0$. So those who assembled that "test" definitely failed.

Comment: @NoNames So, we know that a<0.

Comment: You should give all the avalaible information like this $a<0$. Besides, are you conscious that the problem can be phrased into "find a certain antiderivative of the integrand".?

Comment: @Anusha Do you have access to the answer of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note $ \sin^{-1}e^x+\cos^{-1}e^{x} =\frac\pi2$ and substitute  $y= \tan^{-1}e^a+ \tan^{-1}e^x$, $dy = \frac{dx}{e^x+e^{-x}}$ to integrate

$$\int_{-\infty}^{a}\frac{\sin^{-1}e^x+\sec^{-1}e^{-x}}{(\tan^{-1}e^a+ \tan^{-1}e^x)(e^x+e^{-x})}\mathrm{d}x
=\frac\pi2 \int_{ \tan^{-1}e^a}^{2\tan^{-1}e^a}\frac1ydy=\frac\pi2\ln2
$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{gather*}
Let\ I=\int ^{a}_{-\infty }\frac{\arcsin\left( e^{x}\right) +\ \arcsec\left( e^{-x}\right)}{\left( c+\arctan\left( e^{x}\right)\right)\left( e^{x} +e^{-x}\right)} dx\\
=\int ^{a}_{-\infty }\frac{\arcsin\left( e^{x}\right) +\arccos\left( e^{x}\right)}{\left( c+\arctan\left( e^{x}\right)\right)\left( e^{x} +e^{-x}\right)} dx\\
\left( As\ \arcsec( 1/t) =\arccos( t) \ for\ all\ t >0\ and\ e^{x}  >0\ for\ all\ x\right)\\
=\int ^{a}_{-\infty }\frac{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\left( c+\arctan\left( e^{x}\right)\right)\left( e^{x} +e^{-x}\right)} dx=\frac{\pi }{2}\int ^{e^{a}}_{0}\frac{e^{x} dx}{\left( c+\arctan\left( e^{x}\right)\right)\left( e^{2x} +1\right)}\\
Substitute\ e^{x} =t\\
e^{x} dx=dt\\
I=\frac{\pi }{2}\int ^{e^{a}}_{0}\frac{dt}{( c+\arctan( t))\left( t^{2} +1\right)}\\
Now\ let\ \arctan( t) =u\\
\frac{1}{t^{2} +1} dt=du\\
I=\frac{\pi }{2}\int ^{\arctan\left( e^{a}\right)}_{0}\frac{du}{( c+u)} =\frac{\pi }{2}\ln \mid u+c\mid =\frac{\pi }{2}\ln\left(\frac{\arctan\left( e^{a}\right)}{c} +1\right)\\
Remembering\ that\ c=\arctan\left( e^{a}\right) ,\\
I=\frac{\pi }{2}\ln( 2)
\end{gather*}
Hope this answers your question!

Comment: If somebody could please suggest a way to avoid the type error for arcsec(x) in my answer, I would be very glad.

Comment: Well, the question asked to evaluate a definite integral, and it does evaluate to a constant! But if there are any errors in my method, please do point out!

Comment: About "arcec", type it like this "\operatorname{arcsec}"

Comment: It can be constant because a occurs in both the bound and the integrand giving some type of cancellation side effect.

Comment: When you have text inside MathJax, you can make it non-italics by using ``\text{...}``. Eg ``$\text{Hi} ~x^2$`` comes out as $\text{Hi}~ x^2$